# Offline use of Git

Tags: git

How can we use git offline if we have many files and do not have an internet connection? Or can we store our files in just a committed state? And does git have capacity to store files? If yes, then how much?

Comment: - can we use git offline?
- yes.

- capacity?
- depends on your hard disk available space.

Comment: Git does not require an Internet connection. Yes, you can use it offline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use git offline just install git, go to the root directory for your files and run `git init` to initialize the repository. You can then run `git add file_path`, `git commit -m "First commit"` etc.

The repository is stored under the `.git` directory that is created under the directory in which you run `git init`.

Comment: ok thanks and one more thing if we copy paste git folder or files into another PC or folder and then install git in that PC  , then , did that files works or not?

Comment: Yes it will work provided the operating system is the same. You may have to adapt a repository post transferring from say Ubuntu to Windows.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli Note that the `.git` directory **is** the repository with all history information.

Comment: It's not recommended to use the OS `copy` function to duplicate Git repositories. Each clone has its own unique identifier and duplicating it may produce issues in some contexts. Git provide the [`clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) command for this purpose.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli: +1 to axiac, it is advisable to use git clone if possible.

Comment: A clone of a repository doesn't have a unique identifier.  It's an exact copy; that's why the command is called _clone_.  There's nothing wrong with using `cp` or `copy`.

Answer (score 12):

By design, Git keeps the entire project history in each clone of the repository. Most of its operations do not need a network connection.

It needs a network connection only when you want to synchronize your clone with another clone located on a different computer. For example, when you want to make your changes available to your co-workers or get their contributions.

[Read more](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#_nearly_every_operation_is_local) about this item or, better, read the entire [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to learn how it works.

As a side note, if you work alone on a project Git doesn't need a network connection at all. It is, however, recommended to keep a clone of your repository (and synchronize it often) on a different computer (on GitHub, for example) for backup reasons.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use Git offline. Git only requires an Internet connection when you use commands such as `git remote`, `git pull`, and `git push` with a remote repository that is stored on an Internet server. Any other commands that do not interact with a remote repository, such as `git add`, `git commit`, and `git log` to name a few, do not require any network connection. They modify files directly on your local machine in a subdirectory named `.git`. The size of this `.git` subdirectory is only limited by the physical capacity of the storage medium (typically a hard drive) where you save it.

To learn more about these commands, I suggest that you read [Pro Git](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2). This book is available for free online. The first three chapters teach you 99% of what you need for day-to-day use.

Note that Git is separate from GitHub. Since GitHub is a bunch of servers connected to the Internet, you need a Internet connection to use it. When you use GitHub you will use the commands that I listed earlier because your remote repository will be on a GitHub server.

Comment: Thanks . And could you please tell me one more thing that Git GUI is better or Git bash or cmd for beginner in Git ?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli I suggest learning the command line to start. I prefer git bash, but cmd is fine, too. The book I linked in my answer and all of the official documentation uses command-line terminology. Understanding this will help you a lot when you start using any GUI tools.

Comment: Thank you so much and I'm reading that and I'm on chapter 4 I think the same thing as you , that , the basics would be better in future.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.gibbard.me/using_git_offline/) will give you offline scenarios to work with. Copying the `.git` folder is a simplistic approach and more tooling exists within git.

You can use the `git bundle` command to export and clone repos using a single file.

```
; first export
PC1 $ git bundle create repoName.bundle --all
; and clone
PC2 $ git clone /path/to/repoName.bundle

; after a few commits, export again
PC1 $ git bundle create repoName.bundle --all
; and pull
PC2 $ git pull /path/to/repoName.bundle
```